# Importing one JKS file to another leads to java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate

So what I did is I've imported all JKS entries from one JKS keystore to another JKS keystore

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.jks -destkeystore keystore2.jks
Importing keystore keystore.jks to keystore2.jks...
Enter destination keystore password:  
Enter source keystore password:  
Entry for alias my-key successfully imported.
Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
```

and it leads me to `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` which is true because those 2 JKS keystores got different key-store passwords and key passwords. 
How to unite them properly?

Comment: Generally that exception often means you've provided incorrect password. Add the command you are using for important (do not put real password). There should be options to put passwords.

Comment: @MartinStrejc: OP already shows the command, which by default prompts with noecho so the passwords are invisible. OP: do `keytool -keypasswd -keystore newfile.jks -alias my-key` and answer the prompts, or optionally add `-storepass newvalue -keypass oldvalue -new newvalue` . Alternatively, add to the `-importkeystore` at least `-deststorepass newvalue -destkeypass newvalue` and optionally `-srcstorepass oldvalue` for consistency.